# Regular expression to capture a group that is optionally present in Go

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to write a regular expression that in a string representing Go code will replace the name of a type, say `Bar`, with an updated name, say `FooBar`, but only where it appears as the type of a field in another struct or as an array of that type. So I'd like to convert for example

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Bar  Bar
    Baz  []Bar
    Bars []Bar
}
```

into

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Bar  FooBar
    Baz  []FooBar
    Bars []FooBar
}
```

So far, I've managed to convert the array field types using this `ReplaceAllString`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(\w+)(\s+)\[\]Bar`)

    s := `type Foo struct {
    Bar  Bar
    Baz  []Bar
    Bars []Bar
}`

    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(s, `$1$2[]FooBar`))
}
```

which produces

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Bar  Bar
    Baz  []FooBar
    Bars []FooBar
}
```

The replacement of `Bar` is missing as the type of the first field, also named `Bar`. I've tried making the `[]` optional like so,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(\w+)(\s+)(\[\])?Bar`)

    s := `type Foo struct {
    Bar  Bar
    Baz  []Bar
    Bars []Bar
}`

    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(s, `$1$2$3FooBar`))
}
```

But this produces an output where all of the field types are missing:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar
    Baz
    Bars
}
```

What is wrong here? (I could use a two-pass approach with two different regular expressions, but I would prefer to achieve this in one go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the third reference needs to be `${3}`, not `$3`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(\w+)(\s+)(\[\])?Bar`)

    s := `type Foo struct {
    Bar  Bar
    Baz  []Bar
    Bars []Bar
}`

    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString(s, `$1$2${3}FooBar`))
}
```

which produces the desired result

```golang
type Foo struct {
    Bar  FooBar
    Baz  []FooBar
    Bars []FooBar
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your situation, `gofmt` might be a better option:

```
gofmt -r 'Bar -> FooBar' hello.go
```

#### File *hello.go*

```
package hello

type Foo struct {
        FooBar FooBar
        Baz    []FooBar
        Bars   []FooBar
}
```

https://godocs.io/cmd/gofmt

Comment: That seems idiomatic but I actually want to keep the field name `Bar` and only rename the type as in the example above.